# how to ignore missing arguments

Tags: javascript, php

on php side I have a function like this:

```
function getitems($crit, $val, $radio){
...
}
```

On client side I have many ajax functions targeting php `getitems` but some of them have only one or two arguments.

And - getting error - missing arguments.

I usually use fake (empty or whatever) arguments instead, but maybe there is a way to tell - `ignore missing arguments and continue...`.

Writing a new function with corresponding arguments is not desired solution because it would repeat a large part of `getitems`.

Yes, I can write a new function with common code and pass arguments from `getitems` to it, but I'd rather to stay on one single function.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the arguments default values in the function definition, then they become optional:

```
function getitems($crit, $val = null, $radio = null)
{
}
```

This allows you to do:

```
getitems($crit);
```

[Edit] You can then skip arguments with a null:

```
getitems($crit, null, $radio);
```

Alternatively, if the parameters have strict types, you can use the new nullable type hints:

```
function getitems($crit, ?int $val, ?int $radio) { ... }
```

Comment: and what if the next function have a value in `$radio` for example.

Comment: @puerto php supports only positional arguments. You can send an associative array if don't want to set default values at points of  missed arguments

Comment: @splash58, could you write an example, pls

Comment: @puerto See edit.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, I see, thanks a lot

Comment: `f(['arg1'=>'abcd]); function f($array) { if(isset($array['arg1'])  echo $array['arg1']; }`

Comment: @splash58, thanks, a lot of news for me